# Send data and n files to API with Laravel and Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I am making a form in Laravel with the Guzzle library in which documents and information are sent through an API. When testing the API from Postman, it works correctly. I attach the example:

The problem is that when passing it to code, it does not show any error, in fact it shows status 200 but it does not show me the body of the response. And validating on the endpoint, the information is not being sent.

[image: Request API Postman]

[image: Response API Postman]

```
try {
            $token = Controller::token();
            $url = "https://url/api/students/init/store/2";

            $client = new Client();

            foreach ($dataEspEncrypt as $indice => $dato) {
                if (isset($especialidadFiles['specialidadFile'][0][$indice])) {
                    $files = $especialidadFiles['specialidadFile'][0][$indice];
                    $multipart = [];
                    foreach ($files as $nameFile => $file) {
                        if (is_uploaded_file($file)) {
                            // Preparar los archivos correspondientes a este conjunto de datos
                            $multipart[] = [
                                'name'     => $nameFile,
                                'contents' => fopen($file->getRealPath(), 'r'),
                                'filename' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                                'headers'  => [
                                    'Content-Type' => $file->getClientMimeType(),
                                ],
                            ];
                        } else {
                            echo "El archivo $nameFile no se pudo adjuntar." . "<br>";
                        }
                    }

                    $multipart[] = [
                        'name'     => 'tch_uID',
                        'contents' => '43fref-43r4-4fr477-920f455-8fd6c4c7f',
                    ];

                    $multipart[] = [
                        'name'     => 'data',
                        'contents' => json_encode(['especialidad' => $dato]),
                    ];

                    // dd($multipart);

                    // Realizar la solicitud HTTP para enviar el dato
                    $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
                        'headers'   => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token],
                        'multipart' => $multipart,
                    ]);

                    $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
                    dd($statusCode);
                    if ($statusCode === 200) {
                        echo "Solicitud enviada"."<br>";
                        $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
                        $responseData = json_decode($body, true);
                        dd($responseData);
                    } else {
                        echo "La solicitud no fue exitosa: " . $statusCode;
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "No se encontraron archivos asociados al conjunto de datos." . "<br>";
                }
            }
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            echo "Error en la solicitud: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

I also share the value of `$multipart` which is the variable where the data and files are stored

[image: dd $mulstipart]

I am new to using APIs and Laravel, I greatly appreciate your attention and help.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, from your question it's not clear to me what is not working as expected.
When you write "And validating on the endpoint, the information is not being sent", do you mean that you have debugged the payload received on `https://url/api/students/init/store/2` and this payload is empty ?

Comment: Hi! An apology for not being clear, the payload is the value of $multipart that you attach as a screenshot.

Comment: This `$multipart` is the value that you have in your application, not the one received on the external API `https://url/...`, correct ?
If you have control on this external API, I would suggest to debug there the payload received. 
If you don't have control, in order to debug I would try a simpler API call, without attachment files who often complicate things.

Comment: There is parameters in your postman screenshot, that I don't see in your dump of your multipart structure, and vice versa. We really can't tell what you'd actually _need_ to send, based on that.